# Blend a YUY2 format with background

Tags: wpf, alpha, blend, rgba

On a university project I'm working on, a process gets a YUY2 color image, and extracts a mask from that image.
The mask has two possible values- opaque or transparent.
The program renders to screen- using RGBA format with WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation).
The only given unchangeable fact is the YUY2 input.
I would like to avoid the conversion - for efficiency and quality.

Is it possible to render an image + mask to screen using a different format/method, that uses YUY2 directly?